# Deriving value from textfield to javascript(DOM issue)!

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom, runtime-error

In my palindrome checker, i can't obtain value from the HTML input text-field. I tried various methods including query-selectors. But nonetheless is working. Error in the validator is **document.getElement(...) is null.**

i need to find whats wrong with my code. Is there any problem in my DOM?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Palindrome Checker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ex.css" type="text/css">
  <!--<script src="ex.js"></script>-->
  <script>
    var i = document.getElementById('boiler').value;

    function check_pal() {
      rev();
      if (i == rev()) {
        alert(i + " is a palindrome");
      } else {
        alert(i + " is not a palindrome")
      }
    }

    function rev() {
      i = i + "";
      return i.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Palindrome Checker</h1>
    <p>- Word limit "18000"</p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="text" id="boiler" name="boiler" /><br>
      <input type="submit" name="palcheck" id="butn" value="Is it a Palindrome?" onclick="check_pal()" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am little sure that my problem is with document model. ***Because i get correct result when i directly assign the value to the variable***. Or else i get **"undefined is not a palindrome"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your script to following

```
<script>    
    function check_pal() {
      // move this line inside the function
      var i = document.getElementById('boiler').value; 
      // rev(); // Also removed this un-necessary call
      if (i == rev(i)) {
        alert(i + " is a palindrome");
      } else {
        alert(i + " is not a palindrome")
      }
    }

   // modify function to take input as argument rather than relying on global variable
    function rev(i) { 
      i = i + "";
      return i.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
  </script>
```

**Reasoning** - When you manually assigned the value of i, then it was running correctly. However, when were trying to read it from the `getElementById`, the element did not existed by then and it throws a JS error (cannot read property 'value' of null), hence, the error (as i was never initialized and remains `undefined`). Move the retrieving of value inside the function where the latest value can be retrieved and stored in i.

Comment: it helped me a lot

Comment: @Mukunth - Good to hear that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Palindrome Checker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ex.css" type="text/css">
  <!--<script src="ex.js"></script>-->
  <script>
    var i;

    function check_pal() {
      i = document.getElementById('boiler').value;

      rev();
      if (i == rev()) {
        alert(i + " is a palindrome");
      } else {
        alert(i + " is not a palindrome")
      }
    }

    function rev() {
      i = i + "";
      return i.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Palindrome Checker</h1>
    <p>- Word limit "18000"</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="boiler" name="boiler" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="palcheck" id="butn" value="Is it a Palindrome?" onclick="check_pal()" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now the i variable gets assigned in the check_pal function and declared in the global space so both functions can access it. I think you should take a close look in [scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) in javascript.